# Expressing a polynomial as a sum of squares

Tags: simplifying-expressions, mathematical-optimization, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

I encountered a degree 4 polynomial in 8 variables `f(a1,a2,a3,a4,b1,b2,b3,b4)` that I suspect can be written as a sum of squares. While [sostools](https://www.cds.caltech.edu/sostools/) in MATLAB would find such a sum of squares decomposition, I am wondering whether a similar package exists for *Mathematica*.

```
f= 2 a1^2 b1^2 + a2^2 b1^2 + a3^2 b1^2 + 2 a1 a2 b1 b2 + 
 2 a3 a4 b1 b2 + a1^2 b2^2 + 2 a2^2 b2^2 + a4^2 b2^2 + 
 2 a1 a3 b1 b3 + 2 a2 a4 b1 b3 - 4 a2 a3 b2 b3 + 4 a1 a4 b2 b3 + 
 a1^2 b3^2 + 2 a3^2 b3^2 + a4^2 b3^2 + 4 a2 a3 b1 b4 - 
 4 a1 a4 b1 b4 + 2 a1 a3 b2 b4 + 2 a2 a4 b2 b4 + 2 a1 a2 b3 b4 + 
 2 a3 a4 b3 b4 + a2^2 b4^2 + a3^2 b4^2 + 2 a4^2 b4^2;
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with a sum of squares? Are you trying to simplify your expression or do you mean squares of polynomials? If so, you might have to use Grobner Basis.

Comment: I mean sum of squares of polynomials, so indeed one would use Grobner Basis to do this. SOSTOOLS does this in Matlab, i want to know if there is an analogous code in Mathematica.

Comment: Take a look at this. I had a similar problem last year and back then Daniel Lichtblau illuminated me with the use of Grobner bases. 
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103007/complex-polynomial-variable-transformation

Comment: Nothing built-in, IIRC; someone will have to implement [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0022-4049(97)83827-3) or a more modern variant of it.

Answer (score 20):

Here is a somewhat heuristic approach, that relies in this case on the SOS having integer coefficients. I will indicate an alteration that gives a numerical approximation in the general case.

Start with the polynomial under scrutiny.

```
ff = 2 a1^2 b1^2 + a2^2 b1^2 + a3^2 b1^2 + 2 a1 a2 b1 b2 + 
   2 a3 a4 b1 b2 + a1^2 b2^2 + 2 a2^2 b2^2 + a4^2 b2^2 + 
   2 a1 a3 b1 b3 + 2 a2 a4 b1 b3 - 4 a2 a3 b2 b3 + 4 a1 a4 b2 b3 + 
   a1^2 b3^2 + 2 a3^2 b3^2 + a4^2 b3^2 + 4 a2 a3 b1 b4 - 
   4 a1 a4 b1 b4 + 2 a1 a3 b2 b4 + 2 a2 a4 b2 b4 + 2 a1 a2 b3 b4 + 
   2 a3 a4 b3 b4 + a2^2 b4^2 + a3^2 b4^2 + 2 a4^2 b4^2;
```

Extract variables. It is homogeneous of degree 4 so we know we seek squares involving products of two (not necessarily distinct) variables.

```
allvars = Variables[ff]
quads = Union[Flatten[Outer[Times, allvars, allvars]]];
n = Length[quads];
```

Create a symbolic matrix for the bilinear form. Use it to make a symbolic such form. Extract the terms, create a new variable for each one.

```
mat = Array[x, {n, n}] /. x[i_, j_] /; i < j :> x[j, i];
mvars = Flatten[mat];
qpoly = Expand[quads.mat.quads];
terms = Apply[List, ff] /. n_Integer*ab_ :> ab
tvars = Array[t, Length[terms]];
```

Now form the difference between this symbolic polynomial and the one of interest. Replace the terms by their new variables. We'll set all of those to zero to solve for the matrix variables.

```
reps = Thread[terms -> tvars];
diffpoly = qpoly - ff /. reps;
```

Now we separate out terms to get a linear system. The "constant" part is independent of terms of interest and we'll just set variables therein to zero. In general this might be a problem but it works fine for this example. We have that constant part, and the matrix variables within it, only because we included more quadratic monomials than we really needed.

```
linpolys = Normal[CoefficientArrays[diffpoly, tvars]];
unneeded = Cases[Variables[linpolys[[1]]], _x];
zrules = Thread[unneeded -> 0];
qpoly2 = Expand[quads.mat.quads] /. zrules;
```

Now use the zeroed variables to form a smaller set of equations.

```
diffpoly2 = qpoly2 - ff /. reps;
linpolys2 = Normal[CoefficientArrays[diffpoly2, tvars]];

(* {0, {-2 + x[11, 11] + 2 x[15, 1], -1 + x[12, 12] + 2 x[15, 3], -1 + 
   x[13, 13] + 2 x[15, 6], -2 + 2 x[16, 12] + 2 x[17, 11] + 
   2 x[20, 2], -2 + 2 x[18, 14] + 2 x[19, 13] + 2 x[20, 9], -1 + 
   x[16, 16] + 2 x[21, 1], -2 + x[17, 17] + 2 x[21, 3], -1 + 
   x[19, 19] + 2 x[21, 10], -2 + 2 x[22, 13] + 2 x[24, 11] + 
   2 x[26, 4], -2 + 2 x[23, 14] + 2 x[25, 12] + 2 x[26, 8], 
  4 + 2 x[23, 18] + 2 x[24, 17] + 2 x[27, 5], -4 + 2 x[22, 19] + 
   2 x[25, 16] + 2 x[27, 7], -1 + x[22, 22] + 2 x[28, 1], -2 + 
   x[24, 24] + 2 x[28, 6], -1 + x[25, 25] + 2 x[28, 10], -4 + 
   2 x[30, 13] + 2 x[31, 12] + 2 x[33, 5], 
  4 + 2 x[29, 14] + 2 x[32, 11] + 2 x[33, 7], -2 + 2 x[29, 18] + 
   2 x[31, 16] + 2 x[34, 4], -2 + 2 x[30, 19] + 2 x[32, 17] + 
   2 x[34, 8], -2 + 2 x[29, 23] + 2 x[30, 22] + 2 x[35, 2], -2 + 
   2 x[31, 25] + 2 x[32, 24] + 2 x[35, 9], -1 + x[30, 30] + 
   2 x[36, 3], -1 + x[31, 31] + 2 x[36, 6], -2 + x[32, 32] + 
   2 x[36, 10]}} *)
```

Solve the system that makes `bmat` into a correct bilinear form for this polynomial. Plug in the solutions. We do not get values for all variables so some work remains.

```
solns = Solve[linpolys2[[2]] == 0];
bmat = mat /. zrules /. solns[[1]];
bvars = Variables[bmat];
```

We'll adjust the "free parameters" so as to make the matrix positive definite. To that end, create a numeric function that finds the smallest eigenvalue, given numeric values for these variables.

```
obj[vals : {_?NumberQ ..}] := 
 Min[Eigenvalues[bmat /. Thread[bvars -> vals]]]
```

Now we want to maximize that smallest eigenvalue. This is fairly slow with `NMaximize`, faster with `FindMaximum`. The latter gives a weaker result and in fact does not quite deliver a viable matrix.

```
AbsoluteTiming[{max, vals} = NMaximize[obj[bvars], bvars]]

(* Out[255]= {111.376033, {-0.00907241340679, {x[11, 11] -> 
    2.01682304768, x[12, 12] -> 0.998652993047, 
   x[13, 13] -> 1.00192521005, x[16, 12] -> 0.995046130758, 
   x[16, 16] -> 0.99609862964, x[17, 11] -> 0.00336991638564, 
   x[17, 17] -> 2.00227052115, x[18, 14] -> 0.00906737456166, 
   x[19, 13] -> 0.986910720933, x[19, 19] -> 1.01376718577, 
   x[22, 13] -> 0.890037586566, x[22, 19] -> 0.985669306087, 
   x[22, 22] -> 1.00413101831, x[23, 14] -> -0.00906106269306, 
   x[23, 18] -> -0.00904096742103, x[24, 11] -> 0.110559251075, 
   x[24, 17] -> -1.98448194582, x[24, 24] -> 2.00494690946, 
   x[25, 12] -> 1.00921451048, x[25, 16] -> 1.01108280433, 
   x[25, 25] -> 1.01123628949, x[29, 14] -> -0.00906007908607, 
   x[29, 18] -> -0.00903941520969, x[29, 23] -> 0.00907237266086, 
   x[30, 13] -> 0.987345323683, x[30, 19] -> 1.02376193674, 
   x[30, 22] -> 0.987031961614, x[30, 30] -> 1.01561654825, 
   x[31, 12] -> 1.00883984845, x[31, 16] -> 1.00918739894, 
   x[31, 25] -> 1.01897692633, x[31, 31] -> 1.00867831993, 
   x[32, 11] -> -1.98669409665, x[32, 17] -> -0.032831980588, 
   x[32, 24] -> -0.0259559271915, x[32, 32] -> 1.99690556219}}} *)
```

One will notice that the smallest eigenvalue is somewhat below zero, which is bad since it means the matrix will not be quite positive semidefinite (so no positive sum-of-squares). But we also see that every value is "near" an integer. We'll round them off and use that instead.

```
vals2 = vals /. Rule[a_, b_] :> Rule[a, Round[b]];
```

Check that this gives our bilinear form.

```
matsolved = (bmat /. vals2);
Expand[quads.matsolved.quads - ff]

(* 0 *)
```

Check that the matrix is positive semidefinite (all eigenvalues must be >= 0).

```
Eigenvalues[matsolved]

(* Out[446]= {4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Form the eigensystem. Normalize the eigenvectors to that the transpose and inverse matrices are the same.

```
{evals, evecs} = Eigensystem[matsolved];
evecs2 = Map[#/Norm[#] &, evecs];
```

Now use square roots of the eigenvalues to form the Cholesky square root matrix.

```
cholmat = Chop[Sqrt[DiagonalMatrix[evals]].evecs2];
```

Check the result.

```
Expand[quads.Transpose[cholmat].cholmat.quads - ff]

(* Out[499]= 0 *)
```

Here is the explicit SoS.

```
(quads.Transpose[cholmat]).(cholmat.quads)

(* Out[501]= (-Sqrt[2] a2 b2 + Sqrt[2] a3 b3)^2 + (a3 b1 + a4 b2 + 
   a1 b3 + a2 b4)^2 + (a2 b1 + a1 b2 + a4 b3 + 
   a3 b4)^2 + (-Sqrt[2] a1 b1 + Sqrt[2] a4 b4)^2 *)
```

Had this rounding trick not worked we could still have found an SoS that approximates the input polynomial. Simply work with the approximate values for that matrix, alter negative eigenvalues to be zero, and use that to obtain the Cholesky matrix. For this purpose the lines below could be used.

```
matsolved = (bmat /. vals);
{evals, evecs} = Eigensystem[matsolved];
evals2 = evals /. aa_ /; aa < 0 :> 0;
```

When the dust settles one gets an SoS correct to two or so decimal places.

An alternative I have not tried is to assume that `NMinimize` is failing to deliver a high precision result, and take what it gives as an initialization for `FindMinimum`. It is possible that a local optimization step with a good starting value might improve on matters. In principle `NMinimize` ought to be doing this already, but it might be using heuristics for the method or other settings that are not good for this particular problem.

Comment: It's annoying that `CholeskyDecomposition[]` chokes in the positive semidefinite case; otherwise, we easily get a test for semidefiniteness for free, and is definitely cheaper than an eigendecomposition.

Comment: @J.M. There is a reason Cholesky decompositions are not used for solving the "normal equations" for a least-squares solution, in the rank-deficient case. That's exactly when the matrix in question is only psd and not pd.

Comment: One could do symmetric pivoting in the semidefinite case (see e.g. Golub/van Loan) if needed, tho. Of course, that adds a bit of complication...

Comment: That's neat, thanks!

Comment: Sir, it seems not to work with for example f = a^4 - 3 a^3 b + 2 a^2 b^2 + b^4 - 3 b^3 c + 2 a^2 c^2 + 2 b^2 c^2 - 3 a c^3 + c^4

Comment: @tthnew Can that polynomial be written as a sum of squares?

Comment: @tthnew I see now that there is a problem with my code. Really more like two problems. If you pose this as a new question I'll answer with the corrected version.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes that polynomial can be written as sum of squares, it's $(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2-3(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a)\geqslant 0.$ I posted a question here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269990/express-polynomials-as-sum-of-squares. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just leaving a reference to @Daniel 's new and improved code in [Express polynomials as sum of squares](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/270033/27951).

Answer (score 6):

The positive definiteness will be handled with the NCAlgebra Suite 5,0 from [here](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC)

With the codes for **convexHull** and **ExtractElements** given [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216373/search-for-squares/216555?noredirect=1#comment565434_216555) you can proceed as follows

```
<< NC`
<< SDP`

PosChar[p_, c_] := ToExpression[StringJoin[ToString[p], ToString[c]]]
SymmetricalMatrix[name_, dim_] := Module[{dummy, vars = {}, i, j, k, c}, dummy = Table[0, {dim}, {dim}]; 
  For [i = 1; k = 1, i <= dim, i++, For[j = i, j <= dim, j++,
  c = PosChar[name, k];
  dummy[[i, j]] = c; 
  dummy[[j, i]] = c; 
  vars = Append[vars, c]; 
  k = k + 1]]; 
{dummy, vars}
]

p = 2 a1^2 b1^2 + a2^2 b1^2 + a3^2 b1^2 + 2 a1 a2 b1 b2 + 2 a3 a4 b1 b2 + a1^2 b2^2 + 2 a2^2 b2^2 + a4^2 b2^2 +  2 a1 a3 b1 b3 + 2 a2 a4 b1 b3 - 4 a2 a3 b2 b3 + 4 a1 a4 b2 b3 + a1^2 b3^2 + 2 a3^2 b3^2 + a4^2 b3^2 + 4 a2 a3 b1 b4 - 4 a1 a4 b1 b4 + 2 a1 a3 b2 b4 + 2 a2 a4 b2 b4 + 2 a1 a2 b3 b4 + 2 a3 a4 b3 b4 + a2^2 b4^2 + a3^2 b4^2 + 2 a4^2 b4^2;
vars = Variables[p]


CCV = convexHull[p]
(* {{2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2}} *)

BV = createBasis[CCV]
(* {{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0,  1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}} *)

Z = FormMonomials[vars, BV]
(* {a4 b4, a4 b3, a4 b2, a3 b4, a3 b3, a3 b1, a2 b4, a2 b2, a2 b1, a1 b3, a1 b2, a1 b1} *)

{matM, varsM} = SymmetricalMatrix[m, Length[Z]];
V = Z.matM.Z
{eV, cV} = ExtractElements[V, vars]
{ep, cp} = ExtractElements[p, vars];
comp = Complement[ep, eV]

If[comp == {},
  {eVp, cVp} = ExtractElements[V - p, vars];
  vars2 = Variables[cVp];
  sol = Quiet@Solve[cVp == 0, vars2][[1]];
  matB0 = matB /. sol;
  Print[MatrixForm[Chop[matB0]]];
  y = Variables[matB0];
  Print[y];
  G = matB0;
  f = Total[y];
  abc = SDPMatrices[f, G, y];
  SetPrecision[abc, 50];
  {Y, X, S, flags} = SDPSolve[abc];
  Print[Flatten[Y]];
  Print[PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[X[[1]]]];
  Print[PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[S[[1]]]]
];
```

NOTE

The module **createBasis** was omitted because it is quite involved. It's purpose is to find the monomials which squared produce the powers found in $f$. As can be verified the polynomial is SOS.

LAST NOTE

As requested, the needed module **createBasis**

```
ConvexDepenentQ[corners_, cand_] := Module[{w, ws}, w = Array[ws, Length@corners];
 1 == Length@
 FindInstance[
  w.corners == cand && Total[w] == 1 && 
   And @@ Table[w[[i]] >= 0, {i, Length@w}], w]];

ConvexReduce[data_] := Module[{corners, ncorners, test}, corners = data;
Do[ncorners = Delete[corners, Position[corners, data[[i]]]];
test = ConvexDepenentQ[ncorners, data[[i]]];
If[test, corners = ncorners];, {i, Length@data}];
corners];

convexHull[data_] := Module[{corners, rd}, corners = {};
Do[corners = 
  Join[corners, 
   Select[data, 
    Min[data[[;; , i]]] == #[[i]] || 
      Max[data[[;; , i]]] == #[[i]] &]];, {i, Length@data[[1]]}];
corners = DeleteDuplicates@corners;
rd = Delete[data, First@Position[data, #] & /@ corners];
Do[If[ConvexDepenentQ[corners, rd[[i]]], , 
 AppendTo[corners, rd[[i]]]], {i, Length@rd}];
ConvexReduce@DeleteDuplicates@corners];

CierreConvexo[data_List, n_] := Module[{}, Return[{True, convexHull[data]}]]
MaxExps[coefs_] := 
 Module[{i, n, r}, n = Dimensions[coefs]; 
  If[Length[n] > 0, 
   For[i = 1; r = {}, i <= n[[2]], i++, r = Append[r, Max[Take[coefs, {1, n[[1]]}, {i}]]]]; Return[r], 
 Return[coefs]]]

GeneraBase[data_] := Module[{n, m, i, expmax, expbase, j, k, nn, m0, p},
  expmax = Ceiling[MaxExps[data]/2];
  expmax = Floor[MaxExps[data]/2];
  n = Length[expmax];
  For[i = 1; m = 1, i <= n, i++, m = m*(expmax[[i]] + 1)]; 
  expbase = Table[0, {n}, {m}];
  For[i = 1; m0 = m, i <= n, i++, p = 1; nn = m0/(expmax[[i]] + 1);
   While[p <= m, For[j = 0, j <= expmax[[i]], j++,
     For[k = 1, k <= nn, k++, expbase[[i, p]] = j; p = p + 1]]]; 
   m0 = nn]; Return[Transpose[expbase]]
  ]

Clear[createBasis]
createBasis[P_List] := Module[{S, nlp, ncp, nls, ncs, sos, ones, zeros, II, CC, BB, P0, m1, l1, l2, limits, si, m2, MM, X, f, s = {}, i},
  S = GeneraBase[P];
  {nlp, ncp} = Dimensions[P];
  If[nlp <= 10, {sos, P0} = CierreConvexo[P, 1], {sos, P0} = 
    CierreConvexo[P, 2]];
  {nlp, ncp} = Dimensions[P0];
   If[Length[Dimensions[S]] == 1, nls = 1; 
   ncs = ncp, {nls, ncs} = Dimensions[S]];
  ones = Table[1, {nlp}, {1}];
  zeros = Table[0, {nlp}, {1}];
  II = IdentityMatrix[nlp];
  CC = Join[
  Join[Join[{Table[0, {ncp}]}, {{0}}, 2], 1/nlp Transpose[ones], 
  2], {{1}}, 2][[1]];
  BB = Join[Transpose[ones], {{1}}, 2][[1]];
  m1 = Join[Join[Join[1/2 P0, -ones, 2], II, 2], zeros, 2];
  l1 = Table[{-1, 1}, {ncp + 1}];
  l2 = Table[{0, 1}, {nlp + 1}];
  limits = 10^20 Join[l1, l2];
  For[i = 1, i <= nls, i++,
   If[nls > 1, si = S[[i]], si = S];
   m2 = Join[Join[Join[{-si}, {{1}}, 2], Transpose[zeros], 2], {{1}}, 2];
   MM = Join[m1, m2];
   X = Quiet[LinearProgramming[CC, MM, BB, limits, Reals]];
   f = CC.X;
   If[f > 0, AppendTo[s, si]]]; Return[s]
 ]
```

PLUS LAST NOTE

Added the method **FormMonomials**

```
FormMonomials[vars_, basefinal_] := 
 Module[{n, m, p, s = {}, i, j, vj, nv, k, dimv}, 
  dimv = Length[basefinal]; 
  If[dimv == 0, Return[s], {n, m} = Dimensions[basefinal];
   For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, p = 1; 
    For[j = 1, j <= m, j++, vj = vars[[j]]; nv = Length[vj]; 
     If[nv > 1, 
      For[k = 1, k <= nv, k++, p = p*vj[[k]]^basefinal[[i, j]]], 
      p = p*vars[[j]]^basefinal[[i, j]]]]; s = Append[s, p]]; 
   Return[s]]]
```

Comment: Nice use of the hull to pare down the candidate monomials in the result. Gets an upvote (despite deplorable usage of Append).

Comment: WhyI can't get SOS by this code?

Comment: Sorry but this answer is pretty uncompleted without the module createBasis. May you please add it so you give actually a full answer and not a partial one?

Comment: @Hvjurthuk Try to include the modules added after LAST NOTE.

Comment: Thanks a lot for completing the answer! It is very use&helpful!

Comment: Could you help me, please. When I type Z = FormMonomials[vars, BV], it gives: FormMonomials[{a1, b1, a2, a3, b2, a4, b3, 
  b4}, {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
   0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
   0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 
   1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
   0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}]

Comment: Included the module **FormMonomials**

Comment: Thank you, sir, after I entered "{matM, varsM} = ...  Print[Flatten[Y]];
  Print[PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[X[[1]]]];
  Print[PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[S[[1]]]]
];", I get https://i.imgur.com/LMrbDWh.png

Comment: @Cesareo Hello, the code in your answer didn't work successfully. I don't know what went wrong. Could you put the complete code in order in the answer? Thank you.