# Search for squares

Tags: programming, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation, algorithm, searching

Could anyone please help me find $a\left(x,y,z\right)$, $b_{i}\left(x,y,x\right),$$c_{i}\left(x,y,z\right)$
and $d\left(x,y,z\right)$ that are sums of squares of polynomials or rational functions
such that

$$
\begin{array}a
        a\left(x,y,z\right)+b_{1}\left(x,y,z\right)\left(x+y\right)+b_{2}\left(x,y,z\right)\left(x+z\right)+b_{3}\left(x,y,z\right)\left(y+z\right)\\
        +c_{1}\left(x,y,z\right)\left(4-x^{2}\right)+c_{2}\left(x,y,z\right)\left(4-y^{2}\right)+c_{3}\left(x,y,z\right)\left(4-z^{2}\right)\\
        +d\left(x,y,z\right)\left(4+xyz-x^{2}-y^{2}-z^{2}\right)
        \end{array}
$$

equals $15(2+x+y)^{2}(2+x+z)^{2}(2+y+z)^{2}-32(3+x+y+z)^{3}$
by Mathematica programming? or could anyone use the Mathematica codes on this page : [Expressing a polynomial as a sum of squares](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133141/expressing-a-polynomial-as-a-sum-of-squares) to find $a\left(x,y,z\right)$, $b_{i}\left(x,y,x\right),$$c_{i}\left(x,y,z\right)$
and $d\left(x,y,z\right)$ for this polynomial?

Here are some Mathemtica codes that I wrote and you may use for the search by Mathematica programming:

```
  p = 15 (2 + x + y)^2 (2 + x + z)^2 (2 + y + z)^2 - 32 (3 + x + y + z)^3
 q11 = x + y
 q12 = x + z
 q13 = y + z
 q21 = 4 - x^2
 q22 = 4 - y^2
 q23 = 4 - z^2
 q3 = -4 + x^2 + y^2 - x y z + z^2
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post in a Mathematica snippet with the equation so we can just cut and paste?

Comment: @MikeY  Okay, posted. Best regards.

Comment: @MikeY Could you find or use the Mathematica codes on this page:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133141/expressing-a-polynomial-as-a-sum-of-squares to find a(x,y,z), bi(x,y,x),ci(x,y,z) and d(x,y,z) for the polynomial in the question? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The polynomial

$$
p(x,y,z) = 15 (x+y+2)^2 (x+z+2)^2 (y+z+2)^2-32 (x+y+z+3)^3
$$

has a Newton polytope hull which is

```
NP = {{4, 2, 0}, {4, 0, 2}, {4, 0, 0}, {0, 4, 2}, {0, 4, 0}, {0, 2, 4}, {0, 0, 4}, {0, 0, 0}, {2, 4, 0}, {2, 0, 4}}
```

has all the powers even. Follows a picture for the Newton polytope. In black, the hull.

[image]

The monomials that can generate this set of points (red and black) are

$$
Z = \left\{1,z,z^2,y,y z,y z^2,y^2,y^2 z,x,x z,x z^2,x y,x y z,x y^2,x^2,x^2 z,x^2 y\right\}
$$

now

$$
\cases{
a = Z^T\cdot A\cdot Z\\
b_1 = Z^T\cdot B_1\cdot Z\\
\vdots\\
c_3 = Z^T\cdot C_3\cdot Z\\
d = Z^T\cdot D\cdot Z
}
$$

are feasible candidates with $\{A,B_1,\cdots,C_3,D\}$ positive definite matrices. The next step is to determine the conditions such that all the monomials for $p_0(x,y,z)$

$$
\begin{array}a
   p_0(x,y,z) = a\left(x,y,z\right)+b_{1}\left(x,y,z\right)\left(x+y\right)+b_{2}\left(x,y,z\right)\left(x+z\right)+b_{3}\left(x,y,z\right)\left(y+z\right)\\
    +c_{1}\left(x,y,z\right)\left(4-x^{2}\right)+c_{2}\left(x,y,z\right)\left(4-y^{2}\right)+c_{3}\left(x,y,z\right)\left(4-z^{2}\right)\\
    +d\left(x,y,z\right)\left(4+xyz-x^{2}-y^{2}-z^{2}\right)
    \end{array}
$$

are contained in the former Newton polytope. Those linear conditions $R(A,B_1,\cdots,C_3,D)$ are obtained as

$$
p(x,y,z) - p_0(x,y,z) = 0, \ \ \forall \{x,y,z\}
$$

so the problem is reduced to:

Determine $\{A,B_1,\cdots,C_3,D\}$ positive definite, subjected to $R(A,B_1,\cdots,C_3,D)$

Resuming, we need some procedures to handle the symbolic, and a positiveness solver like CXV.

NOTE

The Newton polytope can be extracted with the script.

```
ExtractElements[f_, vars_] := Module[{rf, rf0, nrf, ef, cf},
rf = CoefficientRules[f, vars];
nrf = Length[rf];
If[nrf == 1, rf0 = rf[[1]], rf0 = rf];
ef = Map[First, rf0];
cf = Map[Last, rf0];
Return[{ef, cf}]]

vars = {x, y, z};
pol = 15 (2 + x + y)^2 (2 + x + z)^2 (2 + y + z)^2 - 32 (3 + x + y + z)^3;

{elems, rels} = ExtractElements[pol, vars]
```

and the convex hull can be obtained using (found in a repository)

```
ConvexDepenentQ[corners_, cand_] := Module[{w, ws}, w = Array[ws, Length@corners];
1 == Length@FindInstance[w.corners == cand && Total[w] == 1 && And @@ Table[w[[i]] >= 0, {i, Length@w}], w]];

ConvexReduce[data_] := Module[{corners, ncorners, test}, corners = data;
Do[ncorners = Delete[corners, Position[corners, data[[i]]]];
test = ConvexDepenentQ[ncorners, data[[i]]];
If[test, corners = ncorners];, {i, Length@data}];corners];

convexHull[data_] := Module[{corners, rd}, corners = {};
Do[corners = Join[corners, Select[data, Min[data[[;; , i]]] == #[[i]] ||  Max[data[[;; , i]]] == #[[i]] &]];, {i, Length@data[[1]]}];
corners = DeleteDuplicates@corners;
rd = Delete[data, First@Position[data, #] & /@ corners];
Do[If[ConvexDepenentQ[corners, rd[[i]]], , AppendTo[corners, rd[[i]]]], {i, Length@rd}];
ConvexReduce@DeleteDuplicates@corners];


CH = convexHull[elems]
```

The linear restrictions can be obtained with **ExtractElements** in the output **rels**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just wondering, how do you know any polynomial for a hull with the powers even is always positive? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is a basic result from SOS theory.

Comment: What you said is correct for SOS of polynomials, but I mean SOS of rational functions. Could you please explain why any polynomial for a hull with the powers even is always positive, or which reference has a clear explanation regarding that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Follow the Parrillo publications: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=2ahUKEwjFsKjDsKvoAhVNBWMBHW9dBc0QFjAEegQIAxAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.princeton.edu%2F~aaa%2FPublic%2FTeaching%2FORF523%2FS16%2FORF523_S16_Lec15.pdf&usg=AOvVaw04OhAnXoSqhDvcPc_V3DgG

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=2ahUKEwjFsKjDsKvoAhVNBWMBHW9dBc0QFjAGegQIBhAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.princeton.edu%2F~amirali%2FPublic%2FPresentations%2FCDC_2016_Parrilo_1&usg=AOvVaw0ld-ICA-1IyGPsu1gGK0lJ

Comment: Thank you for the link, but the reference at the link you gave does not say about Newton polytope. However, the theory in other references says that if f is PSD, then every vertex of new(f) has even coordinates and a positive coefficient. Why is any polynomial for a hull with the powers even always positive? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please. See the paper: One Example of Application of Sum of Squares Problem in Geometry: Ondrej Davidek - South Bohemia Mathematical Letters vol. 18,(2010), No 1,1-16.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Just wondering, what do you mean by "generate" in your answer? or you you mean linear combinations? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Given $Z$, and $M$ a suitable square generic matrix, we have that the quadratic form $Z^T M Z$ has a Newton polytope which contains the $p's$ polytope and has the same hull.

Comment: By the way, do you mean that p "is positive" everywhere? Thanks.

Comment: I assumed that $p$ is positive but to be sure of that it is necessary to verify if it's associated quadratic form is definite positive. We can have a surprise.

Comment: If p is positive, wouldn't b_i, c_i and d_i be all 0? By the way, p is actually not positive everywhere.

Comment: p[6, -6, 4] is -10976, so the expression for is not always positive.

Comment: Could you modify  the Mathematica codes on this page:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133141/expressing-a-polynomial-as-a-sum-of-squares to find a(x,y,z), bi(x,y,x),ci(x,y,z) and d(x,y,z) for the polynomial in the question? Thanks.

Comment: @DanK. I answered the question cited as a way to attend your demand.

Comment: Have you addressed the question on your answer "If p is positive, wouldn't b_i, c_i and d_i be all 0? By the way, p is actually not positive everywhere", and did you see the comment "p[6, -6, 4] is -10976, so the expression for is not always positive" by Bill? Thanks.

Comment: Of course $f$ is not definite positive as the result for **PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[matM0]** is **False**. If $f \ge 0$ and $f = 0$ only for $a_i, b_i = 0$ then $f$ is positive definite.

Comment: Then let's go to the original question, what are the polynomials a(x,y,z), b_i(x,y,x),c_i(x,y,z) and d(x,y,z) that you found by using your approach and Mathematica codes? Thanks.

Comment: @DanK. The big problem here is the definite positiveness verification. Mathematica doesn't have an official package to do that. I have proven the NCAlgebra Suite and problems of low-medium complexity can be easily handled. I incorporated it into the answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133141/expressing-a-polynomial-as-a-sum-of-squares

Comment: Then can you find any $x, y, z$ with $x+y,x+z,y+z,4-x^{2},4-y^{2},4-z^{2},4+xyz-x^{2}-y^{2}-z^{2}\ge 0$ but $15(2+x+y)^{2}(2+x+z)^{2}(2+y+z)^{2}-32(3+x+y+z)^{3}<0$? Thanks.